# Maven does not load OpenJPA from Apache Repository

Tags: apache, maven, repository

I want to use openjpa in my app.

As I am using Maven I added following entries to the pom.xml:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
    </repository>       
</repositories>
</dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
            <artifactId>openjpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
            <artifactId>openjpa-persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
            <artifactId>openjpa-persistence-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

I am using STS on Linux and I updated all dependencies via the context menue, but maven does not fetch one file from the repository. The /M2 dir does not contain any openjpa sources.

What am I doing wrong?

There are other repositories and dependencies, but openjpa does not work.

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run mvn with -U option. This will force maven to update its index for repositories.

When running maven command, does it print some information about downloading these dependencies ?

If problem remains, try running with -X option to have a verbose build and see what happens. 
You can post output here if you need some help

Comment: Thx yodamad! I resolved it myself. I declared the dependency in the _DependencyManagement_ -Section of my pom.xml. So far so good. But I forgot to add it to my server-side pom.xml. So I knew what version to use, but forgot to use it at all :-)